# Streaming Live Audio and Video on internet using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, video-streaming, audio-streaming, live-streaming

i want to implement the live video and audio streaming on my one of the clients website.. and i dont have any idea how to go about, can you guys please help, is it possible that the video captured from Mobile Phone (HD Video), be streamed live over internet.. or how the live video and audio streaming works..  can you guys take me to the right direction from where i can start with...

Thanks

Comment: http://www.google.com.pk/#sclient=psy&hl=en&biw=1280&bih=699&source=hp&q=live+streaming+asp.net&pbx=1&oq=live+streaming+asp.net&aq=f&aqi=g1g-b2&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=448l6784l0l6913l29l24l2l3l3l6l825l10313l0.1.1.2.5.6.4l19l0&fp=4525681afd315025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an dedicated technology called Smooth Streaming ([link](http://www.iis.net/download/SmoothClient)). If you are using easy way try to use Microsoft Expression Encoder 4 Pro ([link](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/encoderpro_overview.aspx)). It's a tool made for encoding it to H.264 and publicating both for streaming and broadcasting. As far as I remeber it was used in last olympic broadcast.

Answer (score 3):

There is an implementation with Web RTC https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-ASPNET-MVC. I have already used this example for live broadcasting audio. You can also see the demo on the following link https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/. I hope it will be useful for someone.